# List all subdirectories and files from outside the document root

Tags: apache, scandir, php

I have a index script that is executed INSIDE the document root thats in:

`/var/www/mywebsite/protected-folder/index.php`

now I have a directory OUTSIDE the document root that contains a list of subdirectories that have files in:

```
/var/www/uploads/LIST OF SUBDIRECTORIES/file
```

When the uploads folder was inside the document root I used this code:

```
<?php
$dir = "/var/www/uploads";
$list = scandir($dir); /* This function sorts dirs */
$list = array_diff($list,array(".","..","index.php"));

echo "<ol>";
foreach ($list as $file)
{
   if (!is_dir($file)) echo "<li><a href='https://mysite.ca/protected-folder/uploads/$file'>$file</a></li>\n";
}
echo "</ol>";
?>
```

However this folder needs to be private from public unless logged in and has access to this script.

how can I create a link to the folder that is outside the document root and if the link is clicked on show the files inside that directory?

EDIT: To make my question more clear the uploads folder will have two tiers of subdirectories which will be an unknown number: `/var/www/uploads/UNKNOWN LIST OF SUBDIRECTORY LEVEL 1/UNKNOWN SUBDIRECTORIES LEVEL 2/ALL FILES (file can be any file type)`

The way this was done before was using apache indexes to allow the user to transverse through the subdirectories. This needs to be secure to prevent direct url access so this is how I want it to work:

1. List all the first subdirectory links (links to all subdirectory level 1)
2. Then once the link is clicked on list all subdirectory level 2 folders that are in subdirectory level 1
3. Finally if that link (subdirectory 2) is clicked on show all the files that are in subdirectory 2

hope that clears things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have doesn't care if the directory is inside or outside the document root. Just link to a PHP file to retrieve the file itself (instead of a link to the file upload since it's not available). To retrieve a file you just need to grab the contents using a script and output it.

Something like this:

```
<?php
$path = '/var/www/uploads';
$file = do_something_to_make_this_safe($_POST['file_to_retrieve']);

$type = mime_content_type( $path . '/' . $file );
$contents = file_get_contents($path . '/' . $file);

header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $file);
print $contents;

?>
```

Note you'll need to make sure someone isn't polluting for file path with things like `..` to try to access forbidden files. (thus the `do_something_to_make_this_safe()`)

Comment: how would I get the post information? this script needs to be automatic and should not get any info from the user. It should simply output the files in each directory

Comment: it could be GET or POST. Your existing app outputs links. Does the user not click those? The link would read something like `<a href="https://mysite.ca/retrieve_file.php?file=somefile.doc">file.doc</a>`

Comment: but the links are connected to directories not files.

Comment: also it wouldn't be a single file to retrieve. It would be an unknown number of files so this would need to be in a for loop. Can you rewrite the function to be more relevant to my question using my code?

Comment: I'm not certain then what you're trying to accomplish. your existing code reads directories and outputs the files in them. My function is an example of what you could do to give you a direction. SO isn't a place to get people to write your code for you. Make it relevant to your needs and if you get stuck then come back and ask.

Comment: also the link in the code provided specifically links to a single file and not a directory. You may need to show additional code or modify what you have to make your question more clear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47194/discussion-between-fixnode-and-cfreak)